# APT "/var/cache/apt/archives" Cache Configuration

Tags: apt, deb, cache, configure

I need to can configure the APT "/var/cache/apt/archives" Cache.

Example:

1. Set "Maximum Folder Cache Size"
2. Get/Set "How much time, have to be passed, to remove an older version of a DEB file"."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I found the solution:

to change the APT Cache Settings create a new file like `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99_new_file`, with a content similar the following one:

```
APT::Archives::MaxAge "0";
APT::Archives::MinAge "0";
APT::Archives::MaxSize "2000";
```

and to get a specific value use a command like this:

`apt-config dump | grep 'APT::Archives::MaxAge' | cut -d'"' -f2`